# Ubuntu 16.04 wired and wireless connection detected but no internet access

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager

[https://superuser.com/questions/756145/ubuntu-14-04-wired-connection-detected-but-no-internet-access][1]

I checked the answer in above link and ping but I get:

**3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms**

Comment: Read `man ip;man ip-route` and do `ip route show`. Do you have a `default` route?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your response guys, Apologies for the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network issue, I connected it with my mobile wifi and it worked.

Because in my network I was able to ping with the gateway and unable to ping 8.8.8.8, so I changed the network and it worked.